# Storing duplicate fields: good or bad

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

Let's say a user has posts table like this:

[image]

Post with *id=1* is the first post that a user has posted. Post with an *id=2* – is the edit that was made to the post, with *id=3* – latest current version of the post.

*post_param_a* cannot be changed throughout versions, as well as *user_id* – they always stay the same since the first version. So we could store it like this:

[image]

So the question is: **would it be better to store it the second way, with no duplication?** This way, to get a current version of user's post we'd have to join the first version and check its *user_id* all the time. **Or is it okay to store duplicate fields in this case?**

*p.s. this is questioned because we want to avoid duplication and accident changes of values that cannot be changed throughout versions, so we want to be storing them all in one place*

Comment: only a goober would do #2

Comment: #1 is denormalized anyway.

Comment: @Drew so what's the best way? splitting off to separate tables?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. I shoot for data normalization. That table above looks like comment data under some hierarchy that should not have denormalized data in it in my book. You would need to show the table or two above it in the hierarchy as there is no clarity here in what any of it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the entity `Post` and look at the simple tuple:

```
ID  User_ID  Post_Param_A  Comment
 1       69           foo  This is a post
```

This is perfectly normalized. However, the post may undergo editing and you want to track the changes made. So you add another field to track the changes. Instead of an incremental value, however, it would make more sense to add a datetime field.

```
ID  EffDate       User_ID  Post_Param_A  Comment
 1  1/1/16 12:00       69           foo  This is a post
```

This has two advantages: 1) if you track the changes, you will want to know anyway when this version was saved and 2) you don't have to find the largest incremental value for the post to find out what value to save with each new version. Just save the current date and time.

However, with either an incremental value or date, there is a problem. In the simple row, each field has a function dependency on the PK. In the version row, User_ID and Post_Param_A maintain their dependency on the PK but Comment is now dependent on the PK *and* EffDate.

The tuple is no longer in 2nf.

So the solution is a simple matter of normalizing it:

```
ID  User_ID  Post_Param_A
 1       69           foo

ID  EffDate        Comment
 1  1/1/16 12:00  This is a post
 1  1/1/17 12:00  An edit was made
 1  1/1/17 15:00  The last and current version (so far)
```

with (ID, EffDate) the composite PK in the new table.

The query to read the latest post is a bit complicated:

```
select  p.ID, v.EffDate, p.User_ID, p.Post_Param_A, v.Comment
  from  Posts p
  join  PostVersions v
    on  v.ID = p.ID
   and  v.EffDate = (
        select  Max( v1.EffDate )
          from  PostVersions v1
         where  v1.ID = p.ID
           and  v1.EffDate <= today )
   and  p.ID = 1;
```

This is not really as complicated as it looks and it is impressively fast. The really neat feature is -- if you replace "today" with, say, 1/1/17 13:00, the result will be the second version. So you can query the present or the past using the same query.

Another neat feature is achieved by creating a view from the "today" query with the last line ("and  p.ID = 1") removed. This view will expose the latest version of all posts. Create triggers on the view and this allows the apps that are only interested in the current version to do their work without consideration of the underlying structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a separate table where you store the `post_param_a` for each `post_id`, then you wouldn't need to have NULL values or duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

**The 1st solution** is better because `user_id` is aligned with the `post_id` and avoid various interpretations.

> This way, to get a current version of user's post we'd have to join the first version and check its user_id all the time.

Do you think about adding a field `timestamp`, so that you can always get the last version of a post?

**In the 2nd solution**, *NULL* could be ambiguous when the data grow. And even querying will be difficult, every SQL should be well designed to think about the *NULL* cases and their specific meanings.

**The 3rd solution** could be a normalization of your table using 2 separated ones, e.g. `post` and `post_history`. As you mentioned in the question that `post_param_a` cannot be changed throughout versions, as well as `user_id` – they always stay the same since the first version. In this case,

- In table `post`, you can store information related to the post which are permanent (won't be changed): `id`, `param_a`, `user_id`, `created_at` ...
- In table `post_history`, you can store informations related to the post which are related to each version / modification: `version_id`, `comment`, `modified_at` ... And you can add a FK constraint for the second table which indicates `post_history.post_id = post.id`